# Migrate database from mysql to postgres via ssh

Tags: mysql, bash, postgresql, ssh

I have a homework problem and i cant quite make it so i'm asking for a bit of help.

Homework is to build a script that send a database from local sql to a postgresql onto virtual machine via ssh.

```
 #!/bin/bash
DATABASE=$1
mysqldump -u root -p'xxxxx' --compatible=postgresql  $DATABASE > Migration.sql | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xx.x psql --username=postgres dump < Migration.sql
```

thats the closest i've been.

it generate something into the postgresql (atleast builds some of the database) when i check if something has changed , but in the terminal from where i'm executing the script it list bunch of errors (That looks like something that should be fixed with `--compatible=postgresql`) lot of syntax errors `"` or with `unlock` words.

Any idea why it seems the `--compatible=postgresql` dosent seem to work as the script shows errors with these compatible-likes errors , or if there is a better/cleaner way to build the script.

Sorry if this is an odd or low level question , still learning this.

Answer (score 0):

First, `>` sends standard output from a command to a file. `|` sends standard output from a command to another command. These are mutually exclusive, and the file redirect "wins":

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt | cat
$ cat foo.txt 
foo
```

So the pipe is pointless.

Second, you are telling `psql` to *dump* the database, instead of importing it. Get rid of the `dump` keyword and you should at least get one step further.

Third, I'm not surprised the `--compatible` flag is still resulting in errors. For one thing, I don't think there's any single format of SQL which will be compatible with every PostgreSQL version. I also expect that it's very much a "best effort" flag, handling some common known breakages but not every conceivable incompatibility.